# Meteor changing another template reactively

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I loaded several templates at startup, 
Once the page is loaded the user can select several items that will define the content of another template. That's where I am stuck.

How after the call of my method and store the result in my session I can send it to the other Template.

I have looked at Deps.Dependency I sure it is very simple in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose on the first template you had a select element you wanted to save the result of :

`<template name="foodSelect">
    <select id="favorite-food"> <option> Taco </option> <option> Burrito     </option> </select>
</template>`

In the helper for that template you can check for an event on that type of input :

```
Template.foodSelect.events({
    "change #favorite-food" : function(event, template) {
        var input = $(event.target).val();
        Session.set('favorite_food', input);
    }
});
```

In your other template you can access this by using `Session.get('favorite_food')` and change the content accordingly.